# PHP MySQL and Calculation Errors

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a few tables to record `users` weight, their old weight in `weight_hisotry` and their points they can score in the `points_history` table.

the problem occurs with me is with the calculation line, it seems to be fine to me but it does not give me the correct result

here is my php code:

```
<?php
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
$username = "";
$weight = "";
$height = "";
$weighthist = "";
$id = "";

if(isset($_GET["u"])){
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
} 

//Fetch all users information This is were WEIGHT is stored.
$user_query=mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1"); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)) {
    $id = $row ["id"];
    $username = $row ["username"];
    $weight = $row["weight"];
    $points = $row['point_hist'];
} /* END OF WHILE LOOP $user_query */

//Fetch all from points_hisotry this is where Point_hist is stored  
$q12 = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM points_history WHERE id='$id'"); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q12)) {
    $id = $row ["id"];
    $points = $row['point_hist'];
}
// submit this information upon change of weight
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){       
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $weighthist = $_POST['weighthist'];
    $point_hist = $_POST['point_hist'];

$exists = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($exists)!=0) {
/* update the description in the database */
```

Here I have points where its stored in the database, so for example if user has 10 points alreadys and they score 10 more points they should have 10 + 10 which equals to 20 points. but somehow when I update the information into points_history I only end up with the updated 10.

I also tested my code with echoing the existing score which comes out correct.

```
/* calculate score */
    $calweight = $weight - $weighthist;
    $point_hist = (($calweight * 10) + $points);

    // insert the post values into weigghthistory 
    mysqli_query($db_conx,"INSERT INTO weighthistory (id, weighthist, date) VALUES ('$id','$weighthist',now())");
    // Update weight in the users table.
    mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE users SET weight='$weighthist' WHERE id='$id'");
    // update points in points_history to the new weight.
    mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE points_history SET point_hist='$point_hist' WHERE id='$id'");
    } /* END OF ELSE IF $exists NOT 0 */
    else { echo "the name does not exist";  }

} /* END OF ISSET SUBMIT */

?>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Profile Update: <?php echo $u; ?></title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["newweight"]["weighthist"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }   
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #updateform{ margin-top:24px;}
        #updateform > div { margin-top: 12px;}
        #updateform > input {width: 200px; padding: 3px;background: #F3F9DD;}       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include_once("template_pageTop.php"); ?>
    <div id="pageMiddle">       
    <div id="usernamecss"> Username: <?php echo $username; ?></div>
    <form action="newweight.php" method="POST" id="newweight" name="newweight" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input id="id" type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id?>" maxlength="16" readonly/>   
    <input id="username" type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username?>" maxlength="16" readonly/>
    <br />
    <div><b>Current Weight: </b>KG <?php echo $weight?> </div>
    <input id="weight" type="hidden" name="weight" value="<?php echo $weight?>" readonly/>
    <br />
    <div><b>Current Points: </b> <?php echo $points?> </div>
    <input id="points" type="hidden" name="points" value="<?php echo $points?>" readonly/>
    <br />
    <input id="weighthist" type="text" name="weighthist" placeholder="Enter New Weight" value="<?php echo $weighthist?>" >
    <br /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update Description"></p>
    <a href="user.php<?php echo "?u=",$username;?>">Go to Profile</a>
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php include_once("template_pageBottom.php"); ?>
    </body>
```

I also want the page to display score and upon submit to refresh the page with the correct score. can anyone suggest how I can go by doing this I am new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should point you in the right direction. Untested. Commented where appropriate.

```
<?php
include_once 'php_includes/check_login_status.php';
$username='';
$weight='';
$height='';
$weighthist='';
$id='';

isset($_GET['u']) ? $username=$_GET['u'] : $username=$_POST['username'];
$username=preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i','',$username);

//Concatenate both of your queries with a JOIN
$user_query=mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT users.*,points_history.point_hist FROM users JOIN points_history ON users.id=points_history.id WHERE users.username='$username' AND users.activated=1 LIMIT 1;");

if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)){
$id=$row['id']; //Empty if no result from query
$username=$row['username'];
$weight=$row['weight'];
$points=$row['point_hist']; //Existing points
}

if($id && isset($_POST['submit'])){ //Also fail if $id is empty
$username=$_POST['username'];
$weighthist=$_POST['weighthist'];
// update the description in the database

// calculate score
$calweight=$weight-$weighthist;
$points+=$calweight*10; //$a+=5 is equivalent to $a=$a+5

// insert the post values into weighthistory
mysqli_query($db_conx,"INSERT INTO weighthistory (id,weighthist,date) VALUES ($id,$weighthist,now());");
// Update weight in the users table.
mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE users SET weight=$weighthist WHERE id=$id;");
// update points in points_history to the new weight.
mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE points_history SET point_hist=$points WHERE id=$id;");
} /* END OF ISSET SUBMIT */

//...

echo $points; //$points will always be up-to-date because of the above. Use where needed.

?>
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

HTML form:

```
<div id="pageMiddle">
<div id="usernamecss"> Username: <?php echo $username;?></div>
<form action="newweight.php" method="POST" id="newweight" name="newweight" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input id="username" type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username?>" />
<br />
<div><b>Current Weight: </b>KG <?php echo $weight;?></div>
<br />
<div><b>Current Points: </b> <?php echo $points;?></div>
<br />
<input id="weighthist" type="text" name="weighthist" placeholder="Enter New Weight" value="<?php echo $weighthist?>" >
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update Description" />
<a href="user.php?u=<?php echo $username;?>">Go to Profile</a>
</form>
</div>
<?php include_once("template_pageBottom.php"); ?>
</body>
```